# about build-in extension Local Tunnel Port Forwarding in vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions, portforwarding

i choose disabled for this extension and i don't know how to enabled this extension again
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWJJY.png)

i remove vscode and install it again but when open the terminal (ctrl + `), this tab PORTS not show[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y06Ek.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can search `@builtin` in your extension tab [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tReN.png), then scroll down in the `features` section untill you found **Local Tunnel Port Forwarding** and enable it.